# Pointwise Convergence of $Z_n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-analysis

Let $\{W_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion. How can I show that

$Z_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (t_{j+1}-t_j)(W_{j+1} - W_j)$ converges to $0$  pointwise? 
[i.e., $Z_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise],

which was defined from each partition $\pi_n=\{t_0,t_1,\dots,t_n\}$ of the interval [$0,t$] where $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=t$.  Denoted by $\|\Delta_n\|=\max(t_{j+1}-t_j)$.

Assuming that in the sequence $\pi_1,\pi_2,...$ of partitions, the number  of  sub-intervals increases to $+\infty$ and that $\|\Delta_n\| \to 0$.

Comment: In your definition of $Z_n$ did you mean to write $W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_j}$ instead of $W_{{j+1}}-W_{j}$?

Comment: You could try to prove that $\lim_n Z_n = \int_0^t W_sds-\int_0^t W_sds$ for each realization with a continuous path.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$|Z_n| \leq \sup_{\substack{|u-v| \leq \|\Delta_n\|\\ u,v \in [0,t]}} |W_u-W_v| \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} = t \sup_{\substack{|u-v| \leq \|\Delta_n\|\\ u,v \in [0,t]}} |W_u-W_v|.$$
Since the Brownian motion has continuous sample paths, we know that $s \mapsto W_s(\omega)$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets for any $\omega \in \Omega$. Thus,

$$|Z_n| \leq t  t \sup_{\substack{|u-v| \leq \|\Delta_n\|\\ u,v \in [0,t]}} |W_u-W_v| \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0.$$